# How can I do console.log in scriptSharp?

Tags: script#

I was trying to find how can I do a simple `console.log()` in script#. Strangely enough I was not able to find how to do this, so I was using `alert()` for this reason with `Script.Alert()`.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this with `Script.Literal`.

For example:

```
String s = "I am the variable";
Script.Literal("console.log(s)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    [GlobalMethods]
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [Imported]
    public static class Console
    {
        public static void Log(string valueToLog)
        {
            //this outputs - console.log();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Debug.WriteLine(). That's the only way to do it. I know there's a thread somewhere on the repo regarding doing it this way.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only way to do it? Because I can do it the way I answered in my answer.

Comment: Yes you can do it your way, but the API was designed to use Debug.Writeline for console outputs. I had that very discussion with nikhil. Technically jamauss' answer below is right too.